# Why doesn't the MOVE_CURSOR show up on OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm working on project and want to see what each of the cursors provided by Swing look like.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        frame.setSize(400, 400);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

However, when I use the crosshair cursor it works.

```
frame.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
```

When I mouseover the frame, it only shows the default cursor. It doesn't change to the move cursor. Are cursor implementations platform dependent?

Comment: *"This just shows the default cursor."*  Even when the mouse is pointing at/hovering over the frame?

Comment: Correct. When I mouse over the frame, the cursor does not change.

Comment: That happens to me too... maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Absent documentation, this may be by design; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21675442/230513).