# move cursor is not displaying on foucus at some point on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, swing, cursor

I have swing based application and whenever we move mouse on a component it displays move cursor icon and by dragging we move that component.I have used code for that.

'mycomponent.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR))'

Its working fine in windows 7,8 properly.Even for others icon it works properly in Mac OS X like
code for.

- Curser.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR
- Curser.WAIT_CURSOR
- Curser.SE_RESIZE_CURSOR
- Curser.HAND_CURSOR"

Only in case of "Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR" it shows default mouse icon and also moving component.I have searched a lot for it and somewhere I found solution using custom mouse icon but I don't want to implement the custom mouse icon.
So have any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this result is intended by design, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18599342/230513), Mac uses will not be surprised if you choose to display `Cursor.HAND_CURSOR` in this context.

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X")) {
    component.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your information.Now i confirmed that it was not my implementation issue.